# php form with multiple item checkbox populate excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, arrays, spreadsheet

I am building a form in php that will send the owner an email with the request and link to a page where a table will show all requests.  I keep getting "array" in the output with the multiple item checklist... Here is what I have

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="multimedia[]" value="Assessment"    />Assessment<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="multimedia[]" value="elearning module" />E-Learning Module<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="multimedia[]" value="Photography" />Photography<br />
```

Video Shoot
   Other

```
<?php
$multimedia = array();
echo implode(',', $_POST['multimedia']);

$multimedia_string = implode(',', $multimedia);
?>
//variables in each cell
$variables = array();
$variables['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$variables['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$variables['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$variables['projectTitle'] = $_POST['projectTitle'];
$variables['$multimedia_string'] = $_POST['$multimedia_string'];
$variables['credentialing'] = $_POST['credentialing'];
$variables['description'] = $_POST['description'];
$variables['results_data_page'] = $results_data_page;
```

Comment: $_POST['multimedia'] will be an array. I don't think you can implode it like a string like that.

Comment: Try adding var_dump($_POST['multimedia']) to your code and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$variables['$multimedia_string'] = $_POST['$multimedia_string'];
```

...to:

```
$variables['multimedia_string'] = implode(',', $_POST['multimedia']);
```

---

*Explanation:*

PHP interprets `$_POST['multimedia']` as an array due to having the square brackets `[]` after the name, as in `multimedia[]`, so you can implode it using the comma as a separator and get a string returned.

---

There are some other issues, so try this instead:

```
<?php

//variables in each cell
$variables = array();
$variables['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$variables['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$variables['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$variables['projectTitle'] = $_POST['projectTitle'];
$variables['multimedia_string'] = implode(',', $_POST['multimedia']);
$variables['credentialing'] = $_POST['credentialing'];
$variables['description'] = $_POST['description'];
$variables['results_data_page'] = $results_data_page;

?>
```

*Issues:*

The first three lines don't seem to do anything.

```
$multimedia = array(); // never populated
echo implode(',', $_POST['multimedia']);

$multimedia_string = implode(',', $multimedia); // still not populated, so implodes to an empty string.
```

A couple things here:

```
$variables['$multimedia_string'] = $_POST['$multimedia_string'];
```

PHP variables are NOT interpolated in single quoted string. In other words, to translate PHP variables from the variable name `$name` to the value, in a string, you need to use either double quotes or HEREDOC:

```
echo "I $emotion you very much.";

$html = <<<EOT

<table>
  <tr>
      <td>We $emotion camping.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

EOT;
```

So `'$multimedia_string'` is simply a string containing a dollar sign and the text *"multimedia_string"*.

The other thing is it appears there is no `$_POST` var with that name or whatever you intended `$multimedia_string` to translate to.

Comment: Thank you so much bloodyKnuckles... I took out the $ and it works perfectly.